# componentWillUpdate after vritual dom diffing done?

Tags: reactjs

I was having some trouble figuring out where exactly the `componentWillUpdate` triggers. The docs say it triggers before render. However in my component the only props changing are `defaultValue`, which does not affect the DOM on udpate. So how come my `componentWillUpdate` is triggering? I was thinking it only triggered after props/state were tested to see if it actually changed the virtual DOM.

Comment: They are two different things, the dom diffing is performed after `render`, the `update` is performed every time a prop changes (you can prevent it returning `false` in `componentWillUpdate`)

Comment: Thanks @FezVrasta that's interesting, can you please explain what you mean by "you can prevent it returning false in componentWillUpdate" please? And so `compoentWillUpdate` doesn't really differe at all from `compoentWillReceiveProps` (ignoring the state param and prevention of componentWillUpdate)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant [`componentShouldUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: please share  code

Comment: First componentWillReceive() then componentShouldUpdate() and then componentWillUpdate() just before render

Comment: Thanks @CodeSingh I think what confuses is me is `what is render`? Is that after virtual dom has found some changes?

Comment: Yes, you are right. When a props or state is changed then render function is called. The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead.

Comment: Thanks @Codesingh I think I'm understanding it more. So I came to conclusion, just because `componentDidUpdate` was called, it does not mean that the HTML was updated.

Comment: componentDidUpdate() will not be invoked during initial render

Comment: Thanks @Codesingh yep I got that much :)

Comment: Happy coding brother :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComponentWillUpdate()` has no bearing on whether the DOM will update.  It's used only as a hook to perform some operations to your props before their rendered. If you want to prevent a component from rendering if the props change then you need to return false inside `shouldComponentUpdate()` note `ComponentWillUpdate()` is not called on first run (mounting) for that you want to use 
`componentWillMount()`

Comment: Thanks DirtyRedz, can you pleae explain what you/the-docs mean by "render". Is that after virutal dom is diffed and has decided there is changes on the virtual dom so it will update? Like if no props changed, would it trigger?

Comment: Yeah on first render it will mount the html to the dom. On subsequent renders it will check for differences in the virtual dom, if any update the dom.

Comment: Render is effectivslly always called and is child components renders. That's why the method shouldComponentUpdate is provided so that you can reduce the number of renders.if your app is very large and don't want the over head of a ton of render checks. On medium to small apps this is not an issue

Comment: I say always i mean when a parent component props or state change it will call render then call render on all its children since react is not opiniated to what your children components are doing.

Comment: Thanks DirtyRedz I think its making more sense now. So there is no lifecycle event that triggers only after differences have been detected on virtual dom?

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate () is called on subsequent renders not on initial.  If the dom updated.  In this method you can compare the previous props to the current.